# raise opacity for first div at same time reduce for second. And looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I have 2 divs with background-image. I want to raise at the same time opacity for first div and reduce opacity of another. And I want to loop that. I want to get the smoothly effect of shifts backgrounds. Is there such a way to do that?

```
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>

.first, .second {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.first {
    background: url(http://placehold.it/350x150);
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0;
}
.second {
    background: url(http://placehold.it/250x150);
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpvrj3ut/)

Comment: Do you have an example, or some code you have tried?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just learning jquery and I havent any example. only html + css.. http://jsfiddle.net/cpvrj3ut/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like that:

So there is an `active` class that changes the opacity and visibility of the `imgHolder`.
If you click on the first image it removes the `active` class on that element and jumps to the next element in the DOM and adds there the `active`class. You could get be more save if you write `next('imgHolder')` so that only the next element with class `imgHolder` gets the `active` class.

I also add a loop. So with the `length` function it counts how much elements with `imgHolder` are in the DOM. In this case 2. So after the second is `active` it goes to the first `imgHolder`.

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/rcc6y1nn/2/

I hope you want something like that.

**UPDATE**
Now with `setInterval` the class changes after one second in a loop.

**HTML**

```
<div class="imgHolder first"></div>
<div class="imgHolder second"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.imgHolder {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-in;
    transition: all 150ms ease-in;
}
.imgHolder.first {
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-350-350-10.jpg');
}
.imgHolder.second {
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-350-350-5.jpg');
}
.imgHolder.active {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var $imgHolder = $('.imgHolder');

$imgHolder.first().addClass('active');

setInterval(function(){
    var $next = $('.imgHolder.active').removeClass('active').next();
    if ($next.length) {
        $next.addClass('active');
    } else {
        $imgHolder.first().addClass('active');
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want not by click) Simply loop by setting timeout.

Comment: If I add div with any class name after that divs, it also resive classname `.active` :( http://jsfiddle.net/CroaToa/wh3fqdrj/1/

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. Create a function, use `jQuery.animate()` in chain on each element to animate its opacity to the inverse of its value. Use the function itself as a callback of the second animate function.

```
<div class="box" id="box1"></div>
<div class="box" id="box2"></div>

var box = $('.box');

function animateOpacity() {

    box.each(function () {

        var opacity = parseInt($(this).css('opacity'));

        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 1 - opacity
        }, 800).animate({
            opacity: opacity
        }, 800, animateOpacity);
    });
}
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/3w70ph0u/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, in your fiddle all working fine! But in my, seems to be some bugs)) http://jsfiddle.net/cpvrj3ut/1/